# How to describe a job done for a long time, with breaks?

Tags: phrase-requests, business-language

I am writing my resume and I want to add that I did freelancing work for about ten years, with off and on periods. If I translate it directly from my first language, I would get:

> Freelance work with fluctuating intensity

I am not sure if this is correct and clear in English.

Comment: *Intermittent freelancer*?

Comment: This isn't a Question about English. If it was, sorry and a job done for a long time, with breaks, has very little meaning. Ask yourself what *I did freelancing work for about ten years, with off and on periods* really means?. If your first language matters, what is it, please?

None of this is relevant here but d'you think whoever scrutinises your
application might have the smarts to count what you did in what time?

State that you were freelance for the whole 10 years but list all the skills, knowledge and experience you actually used… otherwise you will appear  as a fly-by-night.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I am a starter and i did it during my studies (starting in high school). It is nothing big enough to list in detail, just a sidenote that i have already quite some programming experience for my age.

Comment: 3053216, you are selling yourself short… though still, you need to find some WWW pages concerned with CVs, etc… this isn't appropriate here.

Please forever remember I have more than twice heard of more than 600 people applying for one job.

In that context, how much lee-way should the scrutiniser give even the smallest mistake or misunderstanding? How much time, exactly, does he have to spend on your application?

If you care about your future, take your Question to a WWW that cares about CVs… please!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thanks for the advice! I will certainly look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Off and on* is a idiom already.

*I've done freelance work **off and on** for ten years.*

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/off-and-on

> sometimes but not regularly
>   *She’s been taking drugs off and on since she was 16.*

Comment: "off and on" is a bit informal to put on a resume/CV, in my opinion.

Comment: I think @Mari-LouA has a point,  thinking about it more, that phrase is indeed too vague & informal for a CV. Though writing advice is probably off topic, I'd suggest a CV has to be precise. Could you say something like *10 years of freelance; usually 4 contracts per year typically of 4 -8 weeks duration* ?